# Linearly scale a value by screen width

Tags: css, sass

I want to do this

```
 Let sw be screen width, width be a certain element's width.
 1. sw = 1200px, width = 1000px = 1000/1200*100vw 
 2. sw = 940px,  width = 800px  = 800/940*100vw  
 3. 940 < sw < 1200, width = linearly scale within the bounds 1. and 2.
```

In js it is easy
`width_in_pixel = 1000 + ( sw - 1200 ) * ( 1000 - 940 ) / ( 1200 - 940 );`

I know the unit vw, and media query `@media (min-width: 940px) and (max-width: 1200px) {}` but cannot solve this question, so would somebody please help me:

**Is it possible to scale it with pure css/sass (no js)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `calc()` function

```
width: calc( 1000px / 1200px * 100vw)
```

[More Info](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/02/06/calc-css-riddle/) on CSS `calc()`

You can do much more with SASS:

```
$sw = 100vw;

.element {
    width: calc(1000px + ( #{$sw} - 1200px ) * ( 1000px - 940px ) / ( 1200px - 940px ))
}
```

> Note: whenever you’re trying to use Sass variables in calc function, be sure to escape them with #{}

And in order to get exactly what you want, you can use the [Sass Control Directives](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#if)

Comment: Isn't `#{$sd} - 1200px` always = 0 ?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for that, it was a typo. I've edited my answer